# Repeatable texture libgdx

Tags: java, kotlin, libgdx, textures

I have a Texture and a TextureRegion with it inside. I want to repeat it in 1 direction and stretch in another. Any ideas how to do this?

If we want to repeat it in both directions we call

```
textureRegion.texture.setWrap(Texture.TextureWrap.Repeat, Texture.TextureWrap.Repeat)
```

But I am creating edge and want in to stretch image at x axis and repeat at y axis. Something like

```
textureRegion.texture.setWrap(Texture.TextureWrap.Repeat, Texture.TextureWrap.Default)
```

But there is no such value in `TextureWrap` enum.

`Texture.TextureWrap.ClampToEdge` doesn't fit there because it basically repeats edge pixels of texture and doesn't stretch it whole.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally. After all attempts I got how to get effect I need. Posting an answer for case if anyone will need same effect:

```
fun modifyRepeatStyle(_horizontalWrap: Texture.TextureWrap?, _verticalWrap: Texture.TextureWrap?,
                      width: Float=textureRegion.texture.width.toFloat(), height: Float=textureRegion.texture.height.toFloat()){
    var horizontalWrap = _horizontalWrap
    var verticalWrap = _verticalWrap
    repeatHorizontal = _horizontalWrap != null //class variable
    repeatVertical = verticalWrap != null  //class variable
    if (horizontalWrap == null){
        //resize texture if you need
        horizontalWrap = Texture.TextureWrap.ClampToEdge
    }
    if (verticalWrap == null){
        //resize texture if you need
        verticalWrap = Texture.TextureWrap.ClampToEdge
    }
    textureRegion.texture.setWrap(horizontalWrap, verticalWrap)
}
```

Later in code you override Image.setSize() method and paste this here:

```
var regionWidth = width.toInt()
var regionHeight = height.toInt()
if (!repeatHorizontal)
    regionWidth = textureRegion.texture.width
if (!repeatVertical)
    regionHeight = textureRegion.texture.height
textureRegion.setRegion(0,0, regionWidth, regionHeight)
drawable = TextureRegionDrawable(textureRegion)
super.setSize(width, height)
```